# R Searching for elements and their index in an array

Tags: r

I have a matrix with 2 columns as described below:

```
TIME     PRICE    
10        45
11        89
13        89
15        12
16        09
17        34
19        89
20        90
23        21
26        09
```

in the above matrix, I need to iterate through the TIME column adding 5 seconds and accessing the corresponding PRICE that matches the row.
For ex: I start with 10. i need to access 15 (10+5), I would've been able to get to 15 easily if the numbers in the column were continuous data, but its not. so at 15 seconds time, i need to get hold of the corresponding price. and this goes on till the end of the entire data set. my next element that needs to be accessed is 20, and its corresponding price. now i again add 5 seconds and it hence goes on. incase the element is not present, the one immediately greater than it must be accessed to obtain the corresponding price.

Comment: Please clarify why the next element is `20` and not `16` (`11+5`)? Or, if your just continue from the last and `15` didn't exist, but `16` did, would the next be `21` (and thus find `23`)?

Answer (score 1):

If the rows you want to extract are `m[1,1]+5, m[1,1]+10, m[1,1]+15` etc then:

```
m <- cbind(TIME=c(10,11,13,15,16,17,19,20,23,26), 
           PRICE=c(45,89,89,12,9,34,89,90,21,9))

r <- range(m[,1]) # 10,26
r <- seq(r[1]+5, r[2], 5) # 15,20,25
r <- findInterval(r-1, m[,1])+1 # 4,8,10 (values 15,20,26)
m[r,2] # 12,90,9
```

`findInterval` finds the index for values that are equal or less than the given value, so I give it a smaller value and then add 1 to the index.

Answer (score 0):

Breaking the question apart into sub-pieces...

Getting the row with value 15:

Call your Matrix, say, DATA, and 
[1] extract the row of interest:

```
DATA[DATA[,1] == 15, ]
```

Then snag the second column.

[2] Adding 5 to the first column ( I'm pretty sure you can just do this ):

```
DATA[,1] = DATA[,1] + 5
```

This should get you started.  The rest seems to just be some funky iteration, incrementing by 5, using [1] to get the price you want each time, swapping 15 for some variable.

I leave the rest of the solution as an exercise to the reader.  For tips on looping in R, and more, see the below tutorial ( I don't expect it to be taken down any time soon, but may want to keep a local copy.  Good luck :) )

http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/users/vigre/undergrad/reports/VIGRERintro.pdf

Answer (score 0):

As @Tommy commented above, it is not clear what TIME you exactly want to get. For me, it seems like you want to get the PRICE for the sequence 10,15,20,25,... If true, you could do that easily suing the mod (`%%`) function:

```
TIME <- c(10,11,13,15,16,17,19,20,23,26) # Your times
PRICE <- c(45,89,89,12,9,34,89,90,21,9) # your prices

PRICE[TIME %% 5 == 0] # Get prices from times in sequence 10, 15, 20, ...
```